# Why does Dropbox temporary link is not playing videos in ios after xcode update

Tags: video, dropbox, avkit

I have some video files that are available on my dropbox account. Previously, I was requesting temporary link using the following code and playing in Avplayer.

```
 private func sendVideo(path:String, handler: @escaping(_ status: String?)->()){
    
    let url = URL(string: "https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/files/get_temporary_link")!

    // prepare json data

    let json: [String: Any] = ["path": path]

    let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json)

    // create post request
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    // insert json data to the request
    request.httpBody = jsonData
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.setValue( "Bearer \(token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {
            return
        }
        let responseJSON = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
        if let responseJSON = responseJSON as? [String: Any] {
            guard let result = responseJSON["link"] as? String
            else {
                handler(nil)
                return
            }
            print(result,"RESULTSSS ")
            handler(result)
        }
        print(responseJSON,"JSONRES")
    }


    task.resume()
}
```

Here is where i am requesting my video base on button tap

```
self.sendVideo(path: path) { video in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    
                    let videoUrl = NSURL(string: video!)
                    let videoPlayer = AVPlayer(url: URL(string: video!)!)
                    let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
                    playerViewController.player = videoPlayer
                    self.present(playerViewController, animated: true) {
                        if let player = playerViewController.player {
                            player.play()
                        }
                    }
```

Now the video no longer plays. Just a black screen and I am sure the link is working because i tested it. What could reason for that error

Comment: This sounds like the same issue being discussed [here](https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Dropbox-API-Support-Feedback/application-binary-type-returned-for-media-files/td-p/548227).

Comment: adding this part of the code solved the problem
let asset = AVURLAsset(url: URL(string: video!)!,options:["AVURLAssetOutOfBandMIMETypeKey": "video/mp4"]). 

If you want to this code so I can upvote it, I am more than happy

Comment: This should be working again now. Please try again and let us know if you're still seeing any issues.

Comment: It is working alreasy